# Выравнивание картинки и текста в 

Tags: html, css

Мучаюсь, не получается выровнять текст и картинку.
Есть кнопка высотой 30 пикселей (кнопка-картинка).
Вот ее стили:

```
button {
    background: url('/imgs/buttons.png') no-repeat;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    color: #555;
}
```

Я хочу вставить в кнопку не только текст, но и картинку, вот так:

```
button img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

<button>
    <img src="img.png">Отправить
</button>
```

Но получается так, как показано на картинке.

[image]

А именно: текст находится строго по средине кнопки, но картинка смещается вниз на 4 пикселя. Что делать? Если прописать картинке margin (сверху-снизу), то будет съезжать текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант первый:

```
button img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px; /* коррекировать по месту */
}
```

Вариант второй: сделать картинку, как бэкграунд кнопки.

Comment: О, совсем забыл про такую возможность (первый вариант).
Второй вариант не очень, ибо придется много кнопок рисовать.
Отлично, спасибо!